# Multiple Subdomains, Multiple Heroku App and Cloudflare

Tags: heroku, dns, cloudflare, cname

I have a bit of a DNS/Configuration issue. I don't know if SO is the proper stackexchange network to post this.

**My Setup**

I use Heroku for hosting and Cloudflare for DNS Management.

```
Domain          Heroku                 Cloudflare DNS Settings
example.com     example.herokuapp.com  CNAME: example.com=>example.herokuapp.com
                                       CNAME: www=>example.herokuapp.com

sd1.example.com sd1.herokuapp.com      CNAME: sd1=>sd1.herokuapp.com
sd2.example.com sd2.herokuapp.com      CNAME: sd2=>sd2.herokuapp.com
sdn.example.com sdn.herokuapp.com      CNAME: sdn=>sdn.herokuapp.com
```

**My Problem**

I can access example.com and www.example.com from my browser but the subdomains are gives me Cloudflare error 502. On the Heroku settings page, I have added the domains to the app below is what I have

```
Domain Name                DNS Target
sd1.example.com            sd1.example.com.herokudns.com
sd2.example.com            sd2.example.com.herokudns.com
sdn.example.com            sdn.example.com.herokudns.com
```

I know i can use the herokudns or herokuapp for the CNAME but none of it is working.

Please help me find what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Comment: did you find an answer for this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @Justin the first setup I showed in the question worked for me.

I think it was a DNS propagation issue. Give it some time, the DNS should propagate and clear the cloudflare error

Comment: I'll be a bit more patient - I've heard they can take some time. Thanks!